# GNU parallel redirect unique files as input

Tags: bash, io-redirection, gnu-parallel

I have a program that requires input as a file redirected using the '<' symbol. I would like to use gnu parallel to process many runs of this but I can't seem to work out the correct command. This command didn't work as I expected:

```
parallel myprogram < input_{}.txt ::: {1..10}
```

where input_1.txt, input_2.txt, etc. up to input_10.txt are in the current directory with the unique parameters I need to pass to myprogram. Here I got an error:

```
-bash: input_{}.txt: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was almost there. Just needed to add some quotes around the "< input_{}.txt" part as follows:

```
parallel myprogram "< input_{}.txt" ::: {1..10}
```